# StackOverFlow on class property

Tags: c#

#### Duplicate:

> [New to C#, why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

I have a simple class call myClass that has a property called isAuthenticated with the following code:

```
public class myClass
{
        public myClass()
        {
            this.isAuthenticated = false;
        }
        public bool isAuthenticated
        {
            get { return isAuthenticated; }
            set { isAuthenticated = value; }
        }
}
```

When I initalize the class I get a stackoverflow on the set {...} line, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception

Comment: I really wish people would post a comment when they vote to close...

Comment: I've made this mistake myself a fair number of times. krosenvolds answer is correct.

Comment: Might also want to look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx for naming conventions.

Comment: To avoid this mistake, consider auto-implemented properties: public bool IsAuthenticated {get;set;}

Comment: The "vote to close" is almost certainly because of the dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The getter/setter is calling itself. Add a member variable.

```
{
     bool isAuthenticated;
        public myClass()
        {
            IsAuthenticated = false;
        }
        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get { return isAuthenticated; }
            set { isAuthenticated = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: You mean a member variable, not a local variable.

Comment: Yep! I've done this before myself. Kind of like the programming equivalent of biting your tongue while chewing gum.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are setting the myClass.IsAuthenticated property itself.

You have to save the value in a local variable or if you use C# 3.0 or greater just do (automatic property)

```
public bool IsAuthenticated {get; set;}
```

Comment: edited to clarify C# 3.0, not .NET (any specific)

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the "Property-calls-itself" remarks, in the latest C# version you can covert such given simple properties to an *auto-property:*

```
public class myClass
{
    public myClass()
    {
        this.IsAuthenticated = false;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:** changed capitalization of the property, C# naming conventions calls for capital letters as starting letters of a public field or property.

Answer (score 0):

The snake eats its tail. When you assign true to isAuthenticated in the constructor, you use the setter of your property but in the setter, you set it again, so you have some kind of infinite setting loop.

Answer (score 0):

The setter is calling itself, when it should be setting some private field - by the looks of it, the getter will do the same since your example doesn't contain any fields. If you're using .net 3.5 you can just use an auto-implemented property...