# Why doesn't the C# compiler stop properties from referring to themselves?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, exception

If I do this I get a `System.StackOverflowException`:

```
private string abc = "";
public string Abc
{
    get
    { 
        return Abc; // Note the mistaken capitalization
    }
}
```

I understand why -- the property is referencing itself, leading to an infinite loop.  (See previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680765/stackoverflow-on-class-property-closed)).

What I'm wondering (and what I didn't see answered in those previous questions) is why doesn't the C# compiler catch this mistake?  It checks for some other kinds of circular reference (classes inheriting from themselves, etc.), right?  Is it just that this mistake wasn't common enough to be worth checking for?  Or is there some situation I'm not thinking of, when you'd want a property to actually reference itself in this way?

Comment: By "referencing itself", I suppose I really mean to say "recursively calling itself", but you get the idea.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can see the "official" reason in the last comment [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/377005/c-compiler-should-throw-an-error-for-property-getters-calling-themselves).

> Posted by Microsoft  on 14/11/2008 at
> 19:52
>
> Thanks for the suggestion for
> Visual Studio!
>
> You are right that we could easily
> detect property recursion, but we
> can't guarantee that there is nothing
> useful being accomplished by the
> recursion. The body of the property
> could set other fields on your object
> which change the behavior of the next
> recursion, could change its behavior
> based on user input from the console,
> or could even behave differently based
> on random values. In these cases, a
> self-recursive property could indeed
> terminate the recursion, but we have
> no way to determine if that's the case
> at compile-time (without solving the
> halting problem!).
>
> For the reasons above (and the
> breaking change it would take to
> disallow this), we wouldn't be able to
> prohibit self-recursive properties.
>
> Alex Turner
>
> Program Manager
>
> Visual C# Compiler

Comment: It might be nice if they produced a compiler warning about it though. I think that would be valuable.

Comment: Makes sense . . . is it safe to say though that it's probably never a *good idea* to deliberately make a recursive property getter, as it would only ever stop if there were side effects, and (if I understand correctly) methods are preferred to properties in cases where there are side effects?

Comment: @Tim: Those side effects might be internal side effects that are generally , user-invisible side effects.  It is not completely impossible for a property getter to have a side effect (e.g. if you want to keep count of how many times the get was called).  OK, it's still pretty stupid :)

Comment: @Nick A lot of shops pretty are pretty strict about not allowing anything to compile with a warning, so they're pretty stringent about producing warnings for things that may not need them.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/25/why-are-unused-using-directives-not-a-warning.aspx

Comment: @Tanzelax - True, but I find the example in the link you referenced odd, since they explicitly mentioned "useless code" as not being worthy of a warning, yet they produce a warning "The field foo is never used" if you create a member variable foo which you never assign to.

Comment: @Nick: Eric posted another answer in this thread that basically addresses that.  "the code is valid code... But since this is nonsensical code, you probably didn't mean to do it."  You could probably just ask him about it right over there. :)

Comment: @Brian keeping count of how many times a getter was called could be useful -- for instance, you can decide if you want to compute or cache a value based on how often it is accessed.

Comment: @dbkk: When I said it was still pretty stupid, I was referring to the idea of a recursive property getter, not to having a getter which counts how many times it was called.

Answer (score 14):

Another point in addition to Alex's explanation is that we try to give warnings for code which does something that you probably didn't intend, **such that you could accidentally ship with the bug**.

In this particular case, how much time would the warning actually save you? A single test run. You'll find this bug the moment you test the code, because it always immediately crashes and dies horribly. The warning wouldn't actually buy you much of a benefit here.  The likelihood that there is some *subtle* bug in a recursive property evaluation is low.

By contrast, we *do* give a warning if you do something like this:

```
int customerId; 
...
this.customerId= this.customerId;
```

There's no horrible crash-and-die, and the code is valid code; it assigns a value to a field. But since this is nonsensical code, you probably didn't mean to do it. Since it's not going to die horribly, we give a warning that there's something here that you probably didn't intend and might not otherwise discover via a crash.

Comment: I was discussing this the comments on Alex's answer. Your statement that "But since this is nonsensical code, you probably didn't mean to do it. Since its not going to die horribly, we give a warning that there's something here that you probably didn't intend" seems to contradict your blog posting here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/25/why-are-unused-using-directives-not-a-warning.aspx

Comment: @Nick: I'm not seeing the contradiction. (That doesn't mean there isn't one: I am large, I contain multitudes.) I'm just not seeing what you're getting at.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thank you for the Song of Myself reference. :-)

Comment: Thanks for both answers, Eric (this and my question this morning about how to pronounce your name.) For what it's worth, your position seems consistent to me.  You write "we try to reserve warnings for only those situations where we can say with almost certainty that the code is broken, misleading or useless".  `this.customerId = this.customerId` is undeniably useless.

Comment: @Eric - I just found the usings example in that post to be odd. It's certainly useless, and yet you don't warn about it (though I agree I wouldn't want that warning). But the "useless" code is also not a bug (by my estimation). Useless code is not incorrect code, and doesn't cause the software to behave incorrectly. I'm probably parsing all this too precisely.

Comment: @Nick: But as he says in that case it's *automatically generated* useless code . . . and causing it not to be automatically generated would be a nuisance when it's *not* useless.

Comment: @Nick: The difference between the two situations is that in the "unused using" example, the unused using is probably just fluff. It has no meaning whatsoever, it was never intended to have meaning, and it can be removed or kept without making a semantic change. The "assign variable to self" warning was almost certainly *intended to say something else*. We're not merely pointing out that the code is useless, we're pointing out that the code is *likely intended to be purposeful but in fact is useless*, the combination of which is highly likely to be a bug.

Comment: No... I get it. I'm just one of those guys who really like it when the compiler watches my back. Here is a compiler warning situation in VB.NET that has always gotten my goat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337835/no-warning-in-vb-net-when-function-has-no-return

Comment: Walter Bright is also vocally against warnings for code that "crashes loudly". This is why the D programming language doesn't have a NullPointerException.

Comment: Even if not necessarily a *bug*, property recursion is almost certainly *bad practice*. I also disagree with Eric's assertion that the warning would save mere seconds. I'm sure even seasoned programmers might be stumped for a few minutes about where `StackOverflowException`s are suddenly popping up. A simple warning could save valuable time for many developers in this case that is easy to detect, and almost certainly a bug.

Comment: @MgSam an experienced programmer who remembers to look at the exception's stack trace will probably fix the stack overflow in a matter of seconds, not minutes.  Anyway, people who like more hand-holding "did you really intend to do this" messages than the C# compiler provides should get ReSharper or a similar tool.

Answer (score 10):

Property referring to itself does not always lead to infinite recursion and stack overflow. For example, this works fine:

```
int count = 0;
public string Abc
{
    count++;
    if (count < 1) return Abc;
    return "Foo";
}
```

Above is a dummy example, but I'm sure one could come up with useful recursive code that is similar. Compiler cannot determine if infinite recursion will happen (halting problem).

Generating a warning in the simple case would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

They probably considered it would unnecessary complicate the compiler without any real gain.

You will discover this typo easily the first time you call this property.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll get a warning for unused variable `abc`.

Second, there is nothing bad in teh recursion, provided that it's not endless recursion. For example, the code might adjust some inner variables and than call the same getter recursively. There is however for the compiler no easy way at all to prove that some recursion is endless or not (the task is at least NP). The compiler could catch some easy cases, but then the consumers would be surprised that the more complicated cases get through the compiler's checks.

Answer (score 0):

The other cases cases that it checks for (except recursive constructor) are invalid IL.
In addition, all of those cases, even recursive constructors) are guarenteed to fail.

However, it is possible, albeit unlikely, to intentionally create a useful recursive property (using `if` statements).