# Why does this code NOT create a Visual Studio warning about not returning a value on all code paths?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No warning in VB.NET when function has no return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337835/no-warning-in-vb-net-when-function-has-no-return)

While writing the following function, I noticed that I was NOT getting a warning about not returning a value on all code paths. The `CASE ELSE` clause is not returning a value, so it should be giving me a warning. I tried changing the notification level from Warning to Error, but it's still not complaining about it.

```
Public Function LookupOccasionGroup(ByVal occasion As GCOccasionType) As GCOccasionGroups

    Dim occasionInfo = _occasionTypes.FindByOccasionTypeID(occasion)
    If occasionInfo Is Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("blah blah")
    End If

    Select Case occasionInfo.OccasionGroupID

        Case GCOccasionGroups.DineIn, GCOccasionGroups.Delivery, GCOccasionGroups.CarryOut
            Return CType(occasionInfo.OccasionGroupID, GCOccasionGroups)

        Case Else
            Log.Warn("Blah Blah.")
    End Select

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because an `Enum` is not a reference type?! A value type always has a value.

Comment: What i thought, one of the vb.net miracles. Here's the dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2337835/284240

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing VB.NET with a different language; not assigning the return value is permitted in VB.NET. The return value is Nothing, same thing as default(T) in C#. This has always been permitted in Visual Basic.

The screenshot shows a different diagnostic, the one you get when you forget to declare the function return value type. The compiler can now no longer figure out reliably what to return when no assignment is made. It punts for Object and returns Nothing when no assignment was made. That's *very* likely to blow up with an inscrutable NRE exception, thrown at a location that leaves little hint where the true problem is located:

```
Function Foo()
End Function
```

You'll now get:

```
error BC42021: Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed.
error BC31072: Warning treated as error : Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed.
error BC42105: Function 'foo' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.
```

The first two errors are generated by the "Implicit type; object assumed" condition in that same list. The third error is the one you are looking for, and the warning turned into an error by the change. You don't actually want to use this of course.

Comment: I've seen the 'not all code paths' warning many times in VB .Net. I was surprised today to see that it was not warning me for this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the possible values of the enum contained within the first case? If so, then it is conceivable that there's enough intelligence there to believe the else will never be hit.

To test this, either add a new value to the enum, or remove one of the possible values from the first case.

Comment: Actually, after mocking up something similar and trying myself (albeit in 2010 not 2008), this appears to not be the case.  Although in 2010 i DO see the warning