# Is there an automated way to catch property self-assignment?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
class C
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B;

    public C(int a, int b)
    {
        this.A = A;    // Oops, bug! Should be `this.A = a`. No warning
        this.B = B;    // Oops, bug! Should be `this.B = b`. `warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?`
    }
}
```

`A` and `B` are almost exactly the same thing, but one has a bug I will miss.

Is there a way I can get catch the first case at compile time?

**EDIT:** Some of the answers & comments want to explain to me that properties and fields aren't the same thing. I know that already. They explain why the compiler doesn't have a warning here; I get that. But I wrote a bug, and I don't like writing bugs. So my question is "**How can I make sure I never, ever write this bug ever again?**"

Comment: I believe that removing `{ get; set; }` will output a warning and since that `public int A { get; set; }` is the same as `public int A` you do not have to append `{ get; set; }` as they are allowed by default. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY `public int A` is NOT the same as `public int A { get; set; }`. The first is a public field, the second is a public property, Very different things. To the OP; excellent question.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx

Comment: if `C` is a struct then you won't be able to use the `this` statement until all the fields are assigned.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do to force the *compiler* to do anything about it. Ngms answer about FxCop seems a reasonable one. The compiler won't do anything because it's not going to inspect the accessors for the property at the call site, and either the setter or the getter may include behaviour such that it "makes sense" to perform self assignment ("makes sense" in terms of compilable code, not code that a decent developer should write, and it'll almost certainly end up on the daily WTF)

Comment: Added something to my answer after your edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potentially you could use a tool such as FxCop and write a custom rule using VisitAssignmentStatement:

Some examples:
[Example1](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/check_and_visit.html)
[Example2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/1175d46d-00eb-42e5-b944-b031a95c94a5/)

Comment: Also can use CCI and maybe cecil if you dont use fxcop.

Answer (score 4):

You said `A = A` and `B = B` is the same, but this is not true! You can make changes in a property's getter and setter so `A = A` can change the variable like in the example below:

```
public Int32 A
{
    get { return _A++; }
    set { _A = value; }
}
```

So the compiler doesn't know if it is a mistake or not. Of course I would avoid such situations because it's not so easy to work with code like this (e.g. if you just have an assembly and don't know why A is changing each time) and I would avoid exposing an explicit setter of such a property and prefer something like below:

```
public UInt32 UniqueID { get { _UniqueID++; } }

public void Reset()
{
    _UniqueID = 0;
}
```

#### Conclusion

A compile time error isn't making any sense here because the compiler doesn't know what happens in the property (Remember: **A property is just a simplification of two methods, `set_MyProperty` and `get_MyProperty`**), also if the property changes (e.g. by being virtual) the behaviour may change too.

### (EDIT) Avoid misleading naming

I write property and parameters in the same way you are doing it. So as an example of how a simple class might look:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Int32 Sample { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(Int32 sample)
    {
        Sample = sample;
    }
}
```

I'm falling into the same trap like you every week around ~1 time so I never thought about changing the naming. But there are some suggestions of what you could use:

- Use `p`(arameter) as prefix, however this is something which I would not recommend because it makes the code unreadable IMHO.
- Use `value` as postfix, this seems ok for me. So instead of `sample` you would have `sampleValue` which is different to `Sample` (the name of the property) and it should be easier to detect if the property name is used instead of the parameter name
- Use `_` as prefix. I wouldn't use it because I already use `_` as prefix for members to enable fast access to them and makes intellisense look strange IMHO.

I think this depends totaly on you personal or company coding style but i personally would use `Value` as postfix.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't cast-iron, but if you installed ReSharper and set its inspection for 'Unused parameter' to 'Error', and further turned its Solution-Wide Analysis on, you'd see this in the code window:

[image]

One of these red indicators over in the right margin:

[image]

And this down in the status bar:

[image]

Which together make a combo that as a ReSharper user you'd soon become unable to ignore :)

Wouldn't stop you compiling, though.

Answer (score 4):

Jay,

A great question. I believe most of the points which are relevant have been covered in various responses, but just to summarise:

1. There is no way to handle this implicitly. The .Net compiler allows recursive properties, which is at the heart of this issue (in terms of not being able to 'capture' it). Note that, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336847/why-doesnt-the-c-sharp-compiler-stop-properties-from-referring-to-themselves), that's not likely to change.
2. As such, if you want to enforce the capture of this 'bug', you would need to do so explicitly via a 3rd party tool. I'm a ReSharper fan like many others, and that allows us to highlight property recursion where necessary. Also as others have mentioned, using FXCop along with effective Unit Testing patterns will also help you prevent such bugs from arising.
3. Naming conventions are king. By providing an example as you have with deliberately 'useless' (!) variable and property naming, you've highlighted exactly WHY we should all be using an effective naming convention. The issue you highlight is one which has caught us all out, and becomes more pervasive as the code base grows.

Whilst potentially not the answer you were after, I think #3 is the most important point here. Naming items properly is the single most effective solution. Not only that but people might not have the luxury of relying on ReSharper and other such tools.

To that end I'd also recommend [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/). It can be a little invasive, but it is a great tool for helping a developer, or team of developers, adhere to a set of syntax conventions which you'll find will pretty quickly eradicate bugs such as the one you've highlighted.

Happy coding!

Comment: Great advice. The only real way to catch bugs like this is to unit test your methods.  Of course all the other suggestions here will definitely help reduce them from occurring in the first place.

Comment: @bahrens Agreed. This is one of those cases where a combination of these factors is really the only way to 'handle' the problem!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all of the above answers you can also in project properties, under build tab, enable "Treat warnings as errors" with only specific warnings entered. If you are using command line compiler use:

csc /warnaserror C.cs

csc /warnaserror:1717 C.cs

From documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406xhdz3.aspx

This will fail your build either on all warnings or ones you specify.

Comment: I floss, use autopay, and build with warnings-as-errors. But that doesn't help with the problem I described.

Answer (score 1):

In no order:

1. Use VB.NET
2. Unit Test your code.
3. Use ReSharper and accept the prompt "Qualifer 'this' is redundant" - then look for the warnings: `Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?`
4. I saw the FxCop suggestion and thought [Custom Code Analysis Rules using Introspection](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/) was worth mentioning.
5. Use better variable names to identify parameters vs members. This tip is certainly not high-tech. I often compare a variable to a constant, a number, or the return value of a function in a conditional statement. Although it is slightly harder to read, I am in the habit of placing the operand that cannot be used as a l-value on the left-hand side of the == operator, forgetting to type the second equals sign in the == operator will result in a (more than obvious) compiler error (a five-second fix) rather than having to track down the logic error later (a five-minute fix). This point I feel relates to the very minor  syntax error that has just bitten you on the bum.

**Many C# developers declare a variable the same as the type's name, except the first letter in lower case. This practice maybe something you wish to change.**

Comment: #3: qualifying with `this` wouldn't make a warning in this case. #5: I don't see how this is relevant.

Comment: All of this is sound advice except for item 1.  Switching to VB.NET is not practical advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why is self-assignment of field `this.B = B;` is wrong? Because it does nothing. `this.B` and `B` is exactly same thing.

Why is self-assignment of property `this.A = A;` is not wrong? Because meaning of `A` depends on which side of `=` operator it stands. Consider how compiler sees this code:

```
set_A(get_A());
```

This is the invocation of two different methods. Do you think it's a warning if you'll call `Foo(Bar());`? Neither do compiler. It's not good to change backing store in getter, but consider property, where you counting number of readings, or do some logging, or put any other logic. Why would compiler warn you about this?

```
public int A
{
    get 
    {
       _log.Debug("Property A accessed by some user");
       _readingsCount++;
       // your logic goes here
       return _a;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Of couse it's odd, i never said it's a good programming style. :-)

Comment: @FelixK. yep, I understand this :) Just pointed that for OP. I'll remove remark about odd :)