# In C#, why you can set a property to its self

Tags: c#, syntax, properties

Accidentally I created a bug in my work. The cause of the bug is a snippet of c# code like

```
public ClassA{
        public string AProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return AProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                AProperty = value;
            }
        }
}
```

You can build that, and running that without any exceptions.
But it will create an infinite loop. For example, while setting the AProperty, it always tries to assign the value to its self.

Anyone knows why in C# the compiler will allow this syntax?

Comment: Here is the answer you are looking for (or something similar)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336847/why-doesnt-the-c-sharp-compiler-stop-properties-from-referring-to-themselves

Comment: It Is syntactically legal. The compiler isn't there to stop you writing legal but nonsensical code.

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, that's not strictly true.  It stops you from mutating a mutable struct returned from a property.  Such code would be legal but nonsensical if the compiler didn't go out of their way to prohibit it.

Comment: The C# compiler won't stop you from the following, either: `void A() { A(); }`. If won't stop you from `while(true);`, either.

Comment: @Servy heh, but the "get out of jail" card here is that one *is* prohibited (and is thus syntactically illegal) and the other *is not*  (and is thus syntactically legal) :P Yes, that's a bit circular... it is legal because it is not illegal, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell The compiler, in a few rare and specific instances, choose to take code snippets that could be sensibly compiled and made them illegal because the resulting code would virtually never be intended by the programmer, but are common and significant mistakes.  However, they didn't choose to do this in all cases, merely some.  They could have chosen this case; I imagine they thought long and hard about it, but they decided against it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the C# compiler team didn't decide to make this exact case illegal.  Possibly because they didn't consider the benefits of implementing it to be greater than the costs.

It's something that comes up with even the most trivial amount of testing; it's not a very subtle bug, and it's something that developers learn to look for if they get bitten by it a few times.