# Stack overflow exception in C# setter

Tags: c#, setter, callstack, stack-overflow

This works:

```
using System;
using ConstraintSet = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, double>;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class test
    {
        public ConstraintSet a { get; set; }
        public test()
        {
            a = new ConstraintSet();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test abc = new test();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
using System;
using ConstraintSet = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, double>;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class test
    {
        public ConstraintSet a { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
        public test()
        {
            a = new ConstraintSet();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test abc = new test();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
}
```

I get a stack overflow exception on a's setter in the second class and I do not know why. I cannot use the first form because it is not supported by the [Unity game engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)).

Comment: `I cannot use the first form because it is not supported by unity engine` ... The first form is a compiler-level shorthand.  It should work fine with unity engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [StackOverFlow on class property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680765/stackoverflow-on-class-property) and lots of others.

Comment: nope, unity c# compiler does not support this syntax

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you write `a = value`, you are calling the property setter again.

In order to use non-automatic properties, you need to create a separate private backing field, like this:

```
ConstraintSet a;
public ConstraintSet A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
```

Comment: Quite facinating how this process has not changed through all these years.

Answer (score 21):

You haven't declared a backing variable - you've just got a property whose getters and setters call themselves. It's not clear to me *why* the first form isn't supported by Unity - which means it's possible that the equivalent won't be supported either, but it's basically this:

```
private ConstraintSet aValue;
public ConstraintSet a { get { return aValue; } set { aValue = value; } }
```

I'd normally have a more conventional name, of course - which means you can get away without the "value` bit:

```
private ConstraintSet constraints;
public ConstraintSet Constraints
{
    get { return constraints; } 
    set { constraints = value; }
}
```

To give a bit more detail as to why your current second form is throwing a `StackOverflowException`, you should always remember that properties are basically methods in disguise. Your broken code looks like this:

```
public ConstraintSet get_a()
{
    return get_a();
}

public void set_a(ConstraintSet value)
{
    set_a(value);
}
```

Hopefully it's obvious why that version is blowing the stack. The amended version just sets a variable instead of calling the property again, so it looks like this when expanded:

```
private ConstraintSet aValue;

public ConstraintSet get_a()
{
    return aValue;
}

public void set_a(ConstraintSet value)
{
    aValue = value;
}
```

Comment: simply unity c# compiler does not support what visual c# does. this is because it has to mantain compatibility with mono

Comment: @Patrik: Mono supports C# 3 as well... C# 3 has been out for nearly 3 years now; this isn't exactly a new feature.

Comment: i guess this is because of the mac compatibility. i do not know the exact reason but unity compiler says get and set _must_ have a body

Comment: @Patrik: Mac compatibility should have nothing to do with it. They could easily support it if they bothered - it doesn't require any new framework or runtime features. Basically it sounds like the Unity compiler is just somewhat out of date :(

Comment: I can't believe this is a solution. My faith in C# is just about lost....

Comment: @Dan: it's unclear to me what you're objecting to here. The original code is simply broken and recursive - how would you expect C# to behave any differently? Note that Unity has now supported autoprops for some time, I believe.

Comment: It just seems silly to have to have two class variables for each one that you actually want. That's just me, coming from the background of other languages

Comment: @Dan: What makes you think there are two variables? There aren't - there's one field, and one property that provides access to it... just like in Java where you'd have a field and one or two methods to access it. And with automatically-implemented properties, even the field declaration is hidden. Where do you see two variables?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use the same variable name inside the getter and setter. This will cause it to call itself and will eventually lead to a stack overflow. Too much recursion.

You'll need a backing variable:

```
private ConstraintSet _a;
public ConstraintSet a { get { return _a; } set { _a = value; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a private backing variable in your public property:

```
private ConstraintSet _a;
public ConstraintSet a { get { return _a; } set { _a = value; } }
```