# Setter keeps calling itself recursively

Tags: c#, .net

I am practicing events and delegates in C#. When i run the code , i get Process is terminated due to `StackOverflowException`, because the setter is calling itself recursively due to the line:

`CurrentPrice = value; //inside the setter of CurrentPrice`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PriceEvent
{

    public class PriceChangingEvent : EventArgs
    {

        public int Counter = 0; 

        public int CurrentPrice {

            get
            {
                return CurrentPrice; 

            }

            set
            {
                // only invoke the Event when the Class PriceChangingEvent has been instantiated
                if (Counter > 0) // that is when we are not using the constructor
                {
                    CallPriceChanger(this);
                }

                CurrentPrice = value;
                ++Counter; 

            }

        }
        public int NewPrice { get; set; }

        // 2 args Constructor , constructor invokes setter 
        public PriceChangingEvent(int currentprice, int newprice)
        {
            this.CurrentPrice = currentprice;  // invokes the setter of CurrentPrice
            this.NewPrice = newprice;

        }


         //1. define a delegate between publisher and subscribers
         //source publisher who triggers the event,  
        public delegate void CurrentPriceChangeEventHandler(object source, PriceChangingEvent PriceEvent);

        // 2. define an event
        public event CurrentPriceChangeEventHandler PriceChange;

        // 3. raise the event, OnDataTrained is the method which calls the delegate
        protected virtual void OnCurrentPriceChange(PriceChangingEvent PriceEvent)
        {
           PriceChange.Invoke(this, PriceEvent);
        }

        // 3.Function which raises the event, OnPriceChanger is the method which calls the delegate
        protected virtual void OnPriceChanger(PriceChangingEvent PriceChangingEvent)
        {
            // this: the class 
            PriceChange.Invoke(this, PriceChangingEvent);
        }


        // Function to call the function OnPriceChanger
        public void CallPriceChanger(PriceChangingEvent PriceChangingEvent)
        {

            OnPriceChanger(PriceChangingEvent);

        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PriceChangingEvent p = new PriceChangingEvent(20, 30);

            p.CurrentPrice = 45;



        }

        //subscribers

        public static void Display(PriceChangingEvent p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current Price has been changed to {0}", p.CurrentPrice);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is with the "Lorem ipsum..." text at the bottom of your post?  In any event, you need to supply a private backing field to avoid this error.  `private int _currentPrice;`.  Then set that variable in the setter and also return it from the getter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack overflow exception in c# setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276156/stack-overflow-exception-in-c-sharp-setter)

Comment: Have you tried the Getter - it's recursive too.

Comment: By the way, i noticed that your `PriceChangingEvent` class is derived from `EventArgs` and implements an event `PriceChange`. EventArg's (as the name implies) are arguments/data associated with a raised event (they contain any data that needs/should be passed with a risen event). You class name "PriceChangingEvent" suggests that it represents an event, not event arguments, yet it derives from `EventArg`. But not only that, `PriceChangingEvent` is not representing an event either, but `PriceChangingEvent.PriceChange` is. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) `PriceChangingEvent` (which really is an EventArg) having an event also doesn't make sense, since EventArgs should be just arguments for events, not implement events themselves. Your design of your class and the naming of it and of the variables/method parameters/etc. is rather confusing and not really sane...

Answer (score 4):

When you have code that is more than the minimum for the getter or setter, you need a *backing field* for the property:

```
private int _currentPrice;

public int CurrentPrice
{
    get
    {
        return _currentPrice; 

    }
    set
    {
        if (Counter > 0) // that is when we are not using the constructor
        {
            CallPriceChanger(this);
        }

        _currentPrice = value;
        ++Counter; 
    }
}
```

You can further use the backing field to simplify the code, where the constructor can now set the backing field directly, and you no longer need the `Counter` value at all.

```
public class PriceChangingEvent : EventArgs
{
    public PriceChangingEvent(int currentprice, int newprice)
    {
        _currentPrice = currentprice;  
        NewPrice = newprice;
    }

    private int _currentPrice;
    public int CurrentPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPrice; 
        }
        set
        {
            CallPriceChanger(this);
            _currentPrice = value;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```