# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework custom getter setter is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to override getter and setter method in my user.cs model but its not working and I am getting an error when I try to login, when I try to not override, it is working fine.

```
public string UserPassword
{
     get { return this.UserPassword; }
     set { this.UserPassword = value; }
}
```

When I try to login, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PMS.dll

Please check the screenshot.

[image: Error image]

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276156/stack-overflow-exception-in-c-sharp-setter , just for your information , you are using wrong approach , in your case create a custom entity don't override the generated classes from entity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **StackoverFlow exception** : This usually means that you have a recursive call in your code. A recursion is simply a method that calls
>   itself, causing the stack to overflow and throw the StackoverFlow
>   exception

In your case `UserPassword` property calls to itself recursively causing the stack overflow.

You need to change your property like following.

```
public string UserPassword
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Or like

```
string _userPassword;

public string UserPassword
{
    get { return _userPassword; }
    set { _userPassword = value; }
}
```