# Get an unexpected StackOverflow Exception when using properties and an inherited constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

Playing around (for didactic reasons) with inheritance and property in C# a got a strange Exception. Should be a piece of cake for experts, but still baffles me.
Here is my code:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    }
public class Employee : Person
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return ID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (ID < 0 || ID > 999)
                    throw new Exception("Id must between [000-999]");
                ID = value;
            }
        }

        public Employee(string name, int age, int id):base(name, age)
        {
            ID = id;
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var per = new Person("John", 32);
            var imp = new Employee("Michael", 44, 330);
         }
```

Executing that I got a StackOverflow. Last StackTrace point to something wrong at Employee.get_ID () line inside Employee class.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: `public int ID get {return ID;}` returns **itself** and thus you have stack overflow; use backing field instead

Comment: Same for the `set` prop. `ID = value;` is setting `ID` again, recursively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack overflow exception in c# setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276156/stack-overflow-exception-in-c-sharp-setter)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear explanation! So, it's a best practice to always initialize a backing private field when using a property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `ID` property returns *itself*

```
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return ID;
        }
    ...
```

and thus you have *stack overflow*: when you read `ID` it calls `ID` which in turn calls `ID` etc. The same issue with `set`: you assign value to property `ID` which results in assigning value to `ID` etc. To break this *vicious circle*, let's introduce a *backing field*

```
    private int m_ID;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            //DONE: now we just read m_ID, not call the property
            return m_ID;
        }
        set
        {
            //DONE: you want to validate value, not ID, right?
            //DONE: ArgumentOutOfRangeException - value is out of valid range 
            if (value < 0 || value > 999)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value),
                                                     "Id must between [000-999]");

            //DONE: we assign value to the field, not to the property
            m_ID = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `value` is [a bit magical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value).