# Stack Overflow exception while setting static property C#

Tags: c#, properties, static, set, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New to C#, why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

I'm getting a stack overflow exception when I try to set a static property.

```
public static class StaticTest
{
   static string stringToSet
   {
      get
      {                
          return stringToSet;
      }
      set
      {
          stringToSet = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Then, in other class:

```
public void setStaticProperty()
{
    StaticTest.stringToSet = "Hello World";    // StackOverflow exception here
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the stack overflow occurs because your property setter is just calling itself

Comment: use a backing field or auto property.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454902/stack-overflow-exception-while-setting-static-property-c-sharp

Comment: @L.B That took me far too long :)

Comment: The setting code can't be in "other class" (except if the other class is nested inside the same class `StaticTest` that has the property) if your property is `private`. That wouldn't compile, and hence never lead to `StackOverflowException`. In the above code, the property **is** `private`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  set
  {
      stringToSet = value;
  }
```

You got infinite recursion in your setter (and getter for that matter) since it calls itself, hence StackOverflow.

If you don't need to modify the underlying field directly, use an auto-property instead:

```
static string stringToSet {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your static property setter, you are assigning a value to the static property `stringToSet`, which calls your static property setter, where you are assigning a value to the static property `stringToSet`, which calls your static property setter, where you are assigning a value to the static property `stringToSet`, which calls your static property setter, where you are assigning a value to the static property `stringToSet` ...

You need to add a private field to store the property value; usually you'd then rename the property to start with a capital letter (`StringToSet`).

```
private string stringToSet;

public string StringToSet {
    get {
        return stringToSet;
    }
    set {
        stringToSet = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, many thanks for the answer. But with this, I dont have a static property...

Comment: @Guilherme: Sorry, forgot to mention it works the same for a static property if you mark both the field and the property as `static`. But I see you've found your answer already.