# How implement generic repository against mongodb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I am working on mvc4 web application for a new project.

I want to use repository pattern that will talk to a mongodb context for database level communications.

Simple interface that I have used with Entity Framework 4.0 is following. The find members are the problematic area for me. I don't have a clue how to proceed with them with mongodb context.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    //IQueryable<T> FindAll();

}
```

I have a very simple model that is called Hero its drive from ImongoEntity which provides a member called accessId.

```
public class Hero : MongoDB.Kennedy.IMongoEntity
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string _accessId { get; set;}
}
```

Context class is very simple you can see the collection of Heros exposted as IQueryable property.

```
public class MongoDataConetext: MongoDB.Kennedy.ConcurrentDataContext
{
    public MongoDataConetext(string databaseName, string serverName="localhost") : base(databaseName, serverName)
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<Hero> Heros {
        get {
            return base.GetCollection<Hero>().AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my repository most simple methods are add and remove they successfully talk to mongodb context and get entities added or deleted from mongodb. Find method however gives me compiler level errors. I need help for my find and find all method. I am using genrics because I need my repositry class for enties like hero, solution, project, user and category.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IMongoEntity
{
    private readonly MongoDataConetext _ctx;
    public Repository(MongoDataConetext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _ctx.Save(entity);


    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _ctx.Delete(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        _ctx.Heros.Where(predicate);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in an implementation similar to Rob Connery's and NBlog storage code but using the mongodb csharp driver 2.0 (that is asynchronous), you can look at:

https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/mongodb-generic-repository

You can then write a custom repository inheriting from BaseMongoRepository.

```
public interface ITestRepository : IBaseMongoRepository
{
    void DropTestCollection<TDocument>();
    void DropTestCollection<TDocument>(string partitionKey);
}

public class TestRepository : BaseMongoRepository, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(string connectionString, string databaseName) : base(connectionString, databaseName)
    {
    }

    public void DropTestCollection<TDocument>()
    {
        MongoDbContext.DropCollection<TDocument>();
    }

    public void DropTestCollection<TDocument>(string partitionKey)
    {
        MongoDbContext.DropCollection<TDocument>(partitionKey);
    }
}
```

Update: It is now available as its own nuget package:

```
Install-Package MongoDbGenericRepository
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use LINQ against your collections. That's perfect. You can do this much easier if you just expose an IQueryable property rather than write a `Find()` method.

Here's an example from you sample above:

```
public class HeroRepository : IRepository<Heros> where T : class, IMongoEntity
{
    // ...

    public IQueryable<Heros> Heros 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _ctx.GetCollection<Heros>().AsQueryable(); 
            // Careful there, doing this from memory, may be a little off...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, then when you consume this class, just do:

```
var r = new HeroRepository();
var heros = r.Heros.Where(r => r.SuperPowerLevel > 20);
```

Comment: but in this way I have to create multiple concrete classes of repository. for example projectRepository, jobRepository etc. Instead of HeroRepository I want something Repository<T>. and code that will consume Repository<T> will supply actual type for T.

For example inside controller or some service class i will do this.

`var repo = new Repository<Hero>("databasename");`
`repo.Filter(x=>x.SuperPowerLevel > 20);`

Comment: Is it me or does the repository pattern not fit with MongoDB. I feel like it was created more for relational databases. Especially since in Mongo your classes are your collections.

Answer (score 4):

**Generic**

```
public class MongoDatabase<T> : IDatabase<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private static string connectionString = "connectionString";

        private static IMongoClient server = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        private string collectionName;

        private IMongoDatabase db;

        protected IMongoCollection<T> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
            }
            set
            {
                Collection = value;
            }
        }

        public MongoDatabase(string collection)
        {
            collectionName = collection;

            db = server.GetDatabase(MongoUrl.Create(connectionString).DatabaseName);
        }

        public IMongoQueryable<T> Query
        {
            get
            {
                return Collection.AsQueryable<T>();
            }
            set
            {
                Query = value;
            }
        }

        public T GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return Collection.Find(expression).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        public T FindOneAndUpdate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, UpdateDefinition<T> update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T> option)
        {
            return Collection.FindOneAndUpdate(expression, update, option);
        }

        public void UpdateOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, UpdateDefinition<T> update)
        {
            Collection.UpdateOne(expression, update);
        }

        public void DeleteOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            Collection.DeleteOne(expression);
        }

        public void InsertMany(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            Collection.InsertMany(items);
        }

        public void InsertOne(T item)
        {
            Collection.InsertOne(item);
        }
    }
```

**İnterface**

```
public interface IDatabase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    IMongoQueryable<T> Query { get; set; }

    T GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

    T FindOneAndUpdate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, UpdateDefinition<T> update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T> option);

    void UpdateOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, UpdateDefinition<T> update);

    void DeleteOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

    void InsertMany(IEnumerable<T> items);

    void InsertOne(T item);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the properties `Collection` and `Query` will work? These should throw stack overflow exception when set.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ  I've been using it for 3 years. I have not encountered an error

Comment: I am afraid can't believe that. The properties I named are setting `value` to themselves in their own setters, which is exactly like the case in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/). If you've been using it for three years, perhaps these properties have never been set in these three years ;)

Comment: The code would work without the setters. They are not doing anything. To keep the code clean, I would just remove them.

Comment: how to implement Transaction support in GenericRepository. I would really appreciate insight into that.

Answer (score 0):

I know that It's a quite old post, but I would like to share with you the MongoRepository project implemented at [Github](https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository) or download as a [NuGet package](http://ttps://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoRepository/)

**Note:** One of the problem that I had trying to implement the MongoDB Repository has been the different behaviour depending on the MongoDB driver version or wich is more or less the same, the .NET Framework. The MongoRepository project (in the link above) has solved this problem whith different code versions for .net 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5 frameworks that use different version of MongoDB driver (check [MongoDB driver compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/)), wich has been very helpful.