# StackOverFlow-Exception after changing value of Property

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I get a StackOverFlow-Exception when I want to change the value of the property "CurrentState":

```
CurrentState = State.quequed;
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code, instead of image, It appears you are accessing property and not the backing field. That is why it is recursively calling `get`

Comment: Your code is simply calling itself recursively.

Comment: You need to use a backing field for your property. See [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: This is definitely related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception **if not a duplicate**

Comment: Nope, it's not a duplicate. I think I deleted the field which was there before, and I forgot it, so I did not know why this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple logical error and a problem of "infinite recursion" because the `CurrentState` property is attempting to set itself. The solution is simple.

Currently you have this (simplified)

```
public State CurrentState {
    set {
        // ...

        CurrentState = state.Whatever;

        // ...
    }
    get {
        return ???; /// ??? => I don't know what you're returning?
    }
}
```

**Solution:** Create a backing field so the property doesn't call itself.

```
private State _currentState;

public State CurrentState {
    set {
        // ...

        // This is for illustration purposes. Normally you'd be checking 
        // or assigning the value of the "value" parameter, not always 
        // setting the same value as this suggests.
        _currentState = state.Whatever;

        // ...
    }
    get {
        return _currentState;
    }
}
```