# Stackoverflow exception when using many enumarations inside my class

Tags: c#, enums, stack-overflow

I have some enum declarations that for unknown reason to me are causing StackOverflowException.

I have the following:

```
public enum PrimaryAttribute
{
    Strength,
    Agility,
    Intelligence
}

public enum Class
{
    Tank,
    Fighter,
    Sorcerer
}

public class Hero
{
    public PrimaryAttribute PrimaryAttribute { get; private set; }
    public Class Class 
    {
        get
        {
            return Class;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Class == Class.Tank)
            {
                PrimaryAttribute = PrimaryAttribute.Strength;
                IsBlocking = true;
            }
            else if (Class == Class.Fighter)
            {
                PrimaryAttribute = PrimaryAttribute.Agility;
                IsBlocking = false;
                IsDodging = true;
            }
            else if (Class == Class.Sorcerer)
            {
                PrimaryAttribute = PrimaryAttribute.Intelligence;
                IsBlocking = false;
                IsDodging = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my main method I am calling this class and giving a value to Hero.Class

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
hero.Class = Class.Fighter;
```

At this point if I run it I get a StackOverflowException, why?

Basicly I just want to give values to some properties depending on the hero class..

Comment: "compile" or "run"? - it is very rare to see compiler to trow exception, especially StackOverflow.

Comment: It has nothing to do with enumerations. You are implementing your property by calling itself. `public Class Class { get { return Class; } set { ... } }` is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums won't cause a stack overflow.  But this will:

```
get
{
    return Class;
}
```

Your getter for `Class` returns `Class`.  Which is an infinite recursion.

You probably want to store the value in a backing variable:

```
private Class _class;
public Class Class
{
    get
    {
        return _class;
    }
    set
    {
        // your existing logic, but use the variable instead
    }
}
```

Comment: Never happened before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception