# Why does this property cause a StackOverFlow exception?

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, prop

I researched the error a little and it seems like I'm in recursion when the setter is being constantly called but I genuinely can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I know it's probably something simple as well.

```
 namespace PracticeCSharp
 {
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player test = new Player();
        test.Score = 5;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
class Player
{
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return Score;
        }
        set
        {
            Score = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The property returns itself, you're missing a backing field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Score property is recursing on itself.

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
namespace PracticeCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player test = new Player();
            test.Score = 5;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    class Player
    {
        private int score;
        public int Score
        {
            get
            {
                return score;
            }
            set
            {
                score = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively you could do this:

```
namespace PracticeCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player test = new Player();
            test.Score = 5;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    class Player
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there really any point of using these though? It seems like a lot of work.

Comment: You could use auto implemented properties.  I'll update the answer with that alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare score variable

```
 namespace PracticeCSharp
 {    
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player test = new Player();
            test.Score = 5;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    class Player
    {
        private int _score;
        public int Score
        {
            get
            {
                return _score;
            }
            set
            {
                _score = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```