# Assigning value to a static set accessor?

Tags: c#

I have created c# winform program. I need to access 1 patient ID for all the forms. I have created a static class and a static property. But when I assign a value to this(set) property I got a stack overflow exception . I write the code like this:

```
static class Patient
{
    public static int PatientID
    {
        get 
        {
            return PatientID;
        }
         set 
        { 
             PatientID = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Calling program:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbPatient.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        int pid = Convert.ToInt32(cmbPatient.SelectedValue.ToString());

        Patient.PatientID = pid;
        frmDailyCare fdC = new frmDailyCare();
        fdC.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

But it generetes an error. Any one has any idea?
Patient.PatientID = pid; //This line generates the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your `PatientID` setter: `PatientID = value`.  You're recursively calling the same property in the setter (and the getter, too, by the way), so it enters a never-ending recursive call path.

Use either an auto-implemented property:

```
public static int PatientID { get; set; }
```

or add a backing field:

```
private static int _patientID;

public static int PatientID 
{ 
    get { return _patientID; } 
    set { _patientID = value; }
}
```