# Stack overflow exception with no recursion

Tags: c#, console-application, stack-overflow, class-library

I'm having trouble with a stack overflow exception but I can't tell what's causing the exception to be thrown. I'm using a class library that contains all the methods and objects I need and running it from a console application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is part of an assignment that is due in a couple of hours.

Here is my code:

TrafficIncidentNotificationRadiusCalculator class

```
namespace TrafficIncident
{
public class TrafficIncidentNotificationRadiusCalculator
{
    public double meters;
    public double CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS
    {
        get { return CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS; }
        set { CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS = meters; }
    }

    public List<string> GetNotificationRecipientsList(List<User> users, List<UserLocationUpdate> userLocation, TrafficIncidentReport report)
    {
        int i = 0;
        List<string> userNotificationIds = new List<string>();
        while (i < userLocation.Count)
        {
            UserLocationUpdate userLoc = userLocation.ElementAt(i);
            userNotificationIds.Add(userLoc.userNotificationId);
            Console.WriteLine(userNotificationIds.ElementAt(i));
            i++;
        } 
        return userNotificationIds;
    }
}
}
```

TrafficIncidentReport class

```
namespace TrafficIncident
{
public class TrafficIncidentReport
{
    public double[] incidentLocation;

    public double latitude
    {
        get { return latitude; }
        set { latitude = value; }
    }

    public double longitude
    {
        get { return longitude; }
        set { longitude = value; }
    }

    public void SetIncidentLocation()
    {
        incidentLocation = new double[] { latitude, longitude };
    }

    public double[] GetIncidentLocation()
    {
        return incidentLocation;
    }
}
}
```

User class

```
namespace TrafficIncident
{
public class User
{
    public string userFName
    {
        get { return userFName; }
        set { userFName = value; }
    }

    public string userLName
    {
        get { return userLName; }
        set { userLName = value; }
    }
}
}
```

UserLocationUpdate class

```
namespace TrafficIncident
{
public class UserLocationUpdate
{
    public string userNotificationId
    {
        get { return userNotificationId; }
        set { userNotificationId = value; }
    }

    public double lastKnownLatitude
    {
        get { return lastKnownLatitude; }
        set { lastKnownLatitude = value; }
    }

    public double lastKnownLongitude
    {
        get { return lastKnownLongitude; }
        set { lastKnownLongitude = value; }
    }
}
}
```

And then this is the console application that the class library is running from:

```
namespace ClassLibraryTestApp
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        List<UserLocationUpdate> userLocation = new List<UserLocationUpdate>();

        User user1 = new User();
        user1.userFName = "Scott";
        user1.userFName = "Gersbank";
        users.Add(user1);

        User user2 = new User();
        user2.userFName = "John";
        user2.userFName = "Smith";
        users.Add(user2);

        User user3 = new User();
        user3.userFName = "James";
        user3.userFName = "Moore";
        users.Add(user3);

        UserLocationUpdate user1Location = new UserLocationUpdate();
        user1Location.lastKnownLatitude = 0;
        user1Location.lastKnownLongitude = 0;
        user1Location.userNotificationId = "user1";
        userLocation.Add(user1Location);

        UserLocationUpdate user2Location = new UserLocationUpdate();
        user1Location.lastKnownLatitude = 1;
        user1Location.lastKnownLongitude = 1;
        user1Location.userNotificationId = "user2";
        userLocation.Add(user2Location);

        UserLocationUpdate user3Location = new UserLocationUpdate();
        user1Location.lastKnownLatitude = 2;
        user1Location.lastKnownLongitude = 2;
        user1Location.userNotificationId = "user3";
        userLocation.Add(user3Location);

        TrafficIncidentReport trafficReport = new TrafficIncidentReport();
        trafficReport.latitude = 1;
        trafficReport.longitude = 1;
        trafficReport.SetIncidentLocation();

        TrafficIncidentNotificationRadiusCalculator TINRC = new TrafficIncidentNotificationRadiusCalculator();
        TINRC.meters = 20000;
        TINRC.GetNotificationRecipientsList(users, userLocation, trafficReport);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: (Part of the) stack trace would be pretty helpful here.

Comment: In which part it throws an exception?

Comment: *all* of your properties appear to be recursive. (If you're going to supply property method bodies, they shouldn't be referring to themselves)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - You beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wow, sometimes the obvious becomes hardly visible because there is so much of it :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx may be worth a read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a right way to create properties, define a private field, then the property itself: In your case it will call recursively the `set_latitude()` method and cause a stack overflow exception.

Wrong:

```
public double latitude
{
    get { return latitude; }
    set { latitude = value; }
}
```

Right:

```
private double latitude

public double Latitude
{
    get { return latitude; }
    set { latitude = value; }
}
```

Or use [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

```
public double Latitude { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts with a recursive assignment, The first recursion is here :

```
public double meters;
public double CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS
{
    get { return CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS; }
    set { CONFIGURED_NOTIFICATION_RADIUS = meters; }
}
```

**What's wrong:**

> Whenever you set some value to a property it's setter will trigger,
>   and whenever you access the value of a property the setter will
>   trigger. in the above mentioned case, you are assigning the property
>   value in it's setter which will repeatedly trigger the setter and
>   hance you get the exception

See all of your getter and setter are wrong, You should use a backup variable or else use them as `{get;set}`. In the case of `userNotificationId` you should define the property as like the following:

```
private _UserNotificationId
public string UserNotificationId
{
    get { return _UserNotificationId; }
    set { _UserNotificationId= value; }
}
```

Or simply

```
public string UserNotificationId { get; set; }
```