# I am getting a StackOverflowException error for this code. I haven't been able to figure out the error

Tags: c#

I am attempting to make a rock-paper-scissors decision maker with two classes in C#. I think a lot of this may be wrong, so go to town.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Tes
{


 class PlayerApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Player player1 = new Player();
            player1.PlayerChoice = InputValue();
            player1.Classif = InputValue();
            Clear();

            Write(player1);
            Write("\n\n\n\n");
            ReadKey();
        }

        public static string InputValue()
        {
            Write("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors:\t");
            return ReadLine();
        }

    }

    class Player
    {
        private string classif;

        // constructors
        public Player()
        {}

        public Player(string pC)
        {
            PlayerChoice = pC;
        }

        // properties
        public string PlayerChoice
        {
            get
            {
                return PlayerChoice;
            }
            set
            {
                PlayerChoice = value;
            }
        }

        public string Classif
        {
            get
            {
                return classif;
            }
            set
            {
                classif = value;
            }
        }

        public double SetFine()
        {
                    if (classif == "rock")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose paper. You lose.");

            }

                    else if (classif == "paper")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose scissors. You lose.");
            }

                    else if (classif == "scissors")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose rock. You lose.");
            }


            return SetFine();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: `PlayerChoice` seems to call itself, which will result in an instant stack overflow. Shouldn't it be getting the value from somewhere else (e.g. should there be a variable `playerChoice` as you have with `classIf`)?

Comment: You should either use a backing field for the `PlayerChoice` property, or use an auto-implemented property (`public string PlayerChoice { get; set; }`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

Answer (score -1):

**Replace**

```
public string PlayerChoice
{
    get
    {
        return PlayerChoice;
    }
    set
    {
        PlayerChoice = value;
    }
}

public string Classif
{
    get
    {
        return classif;
    }
    set
    {
        classif = value;
    }
}
```

**With**

```
public string PlayerChoice { get; set; }

public string Classif { get; set; }
```

Comment: This would be more useful if you described *why* the original code was a problem (what caused the overflow). Also, there is no problem with the `Classif` property, is there? Also, you can format your code by putting 4 spaces in front of each line, or by selecting the code lines and choosing `{}` from the editor menu.