# In C#, how can I generate a value for a class property only if there isn't one?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, guid, getter, accessor

I have the following **C#** class with a property `Id` which I would like to set with a GUID and return if the consumer calls the value of an instance of myClass.Id for which this value has not yet been set, but otherwise to keep and return the existing value.

```
public class IdentifiableClass{
   public string Id {
          get { 
                if (this.Id == null) {
                    this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("########## Id : " + this.Id );
                }
                return this.Id;
            }
            set => this.Id = value;
   }
}
```

In **C#**, this does **not** work, but rather I get a **stackoverflow** (not this site, obviously).
Best guess, invoking this.Id within the same property's getter seems to resulting in circular logic.

In **Salesforce Apex**, with this *similar* code, it **does** work as *I* would expect it to, evaluating the value of this.Id as null, assigning the value to the new Guid, displaying the value, and then returning the value:

```
public class IdentifiableClass {
   public string Id {
          get { 
                if (this.Id == null) {
                    this.Id = String.valueOf(Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 10)));
                    System.debug('########## Id : ' + this.Id );
                }
                return this.Id;
            }
            set;
   }
}
```

- Is it possible to make this work in **C#**?
- If so, **how**?

Comment: You're right - accessing `if (this.Id == null)` within the getter recursively calls the getter (because that's what `this.Id` calls under the hood). The solution is to use an explicitly-defined backing field, not an auto-property.

Comment: You got a stack overflow because `if(this.Id == null)` calls the getter for the `Id` prop, which you're already in, resulting in infinite recursion. The solution, as noted in answers below, is to use an explicit backing field for the property.

Comment: Cheers. to everyone for solution!.... I'll accept @daniel89's solution in 8 minutes (as soon as StackOverflow lets me), unless someone has a more clever answer.  :-)

Comment: Does it answer you question? [Why does Property Set throw StackOverflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception) It seems to be an exact duplicate

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Your definition of "exact" can use some fine tuning, but it is admittedly a similar question.  On the other hand, that question deals with a very simple use case and does not make clear that any and all attempts to access the property you wish to set from within the accessor is equally doomed to failure.  Perhaps it should be obvious to someone accustomed to C#, but for an Apex developer where this is a common pattern, it is not so obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you should create full property with private field.

```
public class IdentifiableClass{
   private string id;
   public string Id {
          get { 
                if (this.id == null) {
                    this.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("########## Id : " + this.id );
                }
                return this.id;
            }
            set => this.id = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: @MikeH The id field does not need to be initialized since it takes its default value (null) when an new instance of the class is created

Comment: Cheers for solution!.... I'll accept this solution in 8 minutes (as soon as StackOverflow lets me), unless someone has a more clever answer.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is not to use auto-property feature.

You should put explicitly `private string _id;` field and your getters and setters should internaly use that

Comment: Cheers for answer  I'd accept it, but I prefer @daniell89's solution for completeness.